# (SWIFT) How can I refresh data from Parse after dismissing modal viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, reload

First of all, I do not have any tableviews or anything like that - I only have normal UIViewcontrollers.

I have a VC that shows the users firstname (data from Parse), when you click a button named edit, you can edit your firstname in a new VC that is showing through Modal. The code itself is working and it is updating the name in the database, but it is not updating the name in the first VC as I dismiss the editing VC. I have to force close the app and open it again to see the change...

Can anyone help me with an example to solve this? Im going nuts...

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class usersViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var firstnameLabel: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }






    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        if currentUser != nil {
            currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (bruger: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                var firstn: NSNumber = bruger["firstname"] as NSNumber


                self.firstnameLabel.text = firstn.stringValue



            })


        } else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
        }


    }  


}
```

Comment: provide code details to consider your question seriously.

Comment: The code is now added :-)

Comment: Why are you getting the firstname as a number?

Comment: I think you need to refresh CurrentUser

Comment: I guess I have mixed up the code, that should of course be a NSString, but how can I refresh currentuser??

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting the code to refresh the first name in a separate function.  Then call that function in viewDidAppear

```
func reloadFirstName(){
  //Whatever you use to set the label
  //Something like:
  //PFUser.currentUser().refresh()
  //self.label.text = PFUser.currentUser().username
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
  self.reloadFirstName()
}
```

The key is you have to call PFUser.currentUser().refresh() before you get a value from it.